# Activity has register in AndroidManifest.xml,but it will ActivityNotFoundException when Monkey is running

Tags: android, monkey

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.actionxxx dat=sms:xxxxxxxxxxx } 

at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1632)

at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)

at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
```

Comment: Please add code examples for the intent launch, the manifest and the activity

Comment: please add your startActivity code